# Can we use the gerund passively?

Tags: grammar-choice, gerund

In a [recent question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/18988/how-to-say-desire-of-being-loved-praised-etc-in-latin)  it was pointed out that there is no passive gerund, and *cupido amandi* can't mean the desire of being loved. But I'm not sure that this is the case. I tend to view the gerund as signifying the action itself hence it may be used both actively and passively.

This is not the first time I wonder about this issue as seen in my [addendum](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16139/how-to-say-no-one-is-worth-to-be-believed-to-easily-with-dignus-supine) of this post. In which it seems the passive usage of the supine is fine.

Comment: "Ferendo" in the sentence "Superanda omnis fortuna ferendo est. (every fortune is to be subdued by/with endurance)" does not have passive meaning. The implied subject is not "fortuna" but the agent of the subduing. Gerund in ablative expresses a way or manner how an action is performed. You could translate it as "Every fortune is to be overcome by enduring it" -- notice the active form of the verb "endure".

Comment: @Nolmendil, I agree, I gave this as an example to an active meaning. Then my example invented example of *ferendeo* with passive meaning: "by being carried" or "by carrying [them]" though I'm not sure if valid.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add more color and examples to what given in @Tyler Durden's answer which opened the door for me to find more information.

[A Latin Grammar for the Use of Schools](https://books.google.com/books?id=HFwtAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA368&lpg=PA368&dq=%22sometimes%20the%20gerund%20is%20employed%20less%22&source=bl&ots=a9Pt1XyGq6&sig=ACfU3U2sxqKxJY68bjQ6yqQlU3eDRONM0Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi1idzh-YT7AhWB_rsIHVCiBVkQ6AF6BAgJEAM#v=onepage&q=%22sometimes%20the%20gerund%20is%20employed%20less%22&f=false)(p.368) by  Johan Nikolai Madvig:

> § 418. Sometimes the gerund is employed less accurately, so as to have the appearance of a passive signification, inasmuch as it either (especially in the genitive) merely designates the action of the verb in general, and so takes the place of a substantive (e. g. movendi for motūs), or is referred in idea to some other agent than the grammatical subject of the proposition: *Multa vera videntur neque tamen habent insignem et propriam percipiendi notam* (Cic. Acad. II. 31), mark by which they can be known. *Antonius, hostis judicatus, Italia cesserat; spes restituendi nulla erat* (Corn. Att. 9), =*restitutionis* or *fore, ut restitueretur*. *Jugurtha ad imperandum Tisidium vocabatur* (Sall. Jug. 62), that he might receive orders. *Annulus in digito subtertenuatur habendo* (Lucr. I. 313), by our wearing it. (*Facilis ad intelligendum*; see §. 412, Obs. 3.)

The idea, though controversial, seems to be that this is "less accurate" usage and it is not a normal usage. [Here](https://archive.org/details/csallusticrispic01sall/page/n101/mode/2up) (p.182 57) is how Bellum Jugurthinum interprets the above note in his own note on *ad imperandum*:

> Some grammarians unnecessarily consider the gerund used passively here. Madvig,
> § 418, says,  Sometimes the gerund is employed less accurately so as to have the appearance of a passive signification.

There is a [discussion of this issue by Benjamin Hall Kennedy](https://books.google.com/books?id=LBNcAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=%22subtertenuatur%20habendo%22%20gerund&source=bl&ots=vi1OIRfskV&sig=ACfU3U2JASjn3XvyMW9-P025beY2p7GMUA&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22subtertenuatur%20habendo%22%20gerund&f=false), where he brings out more examples:

> *Crescendi* causa haec frequentia convenit (Cic.)

> Ceteris, quae moventur, hoc principum est *movendi* (Sall.)

> Alitur vitium vivitque *tegendo* (Virg.)

Finally, in "An Advanced Latin Syntax" (1919) By A. L. Francis, H. F. Tatum has a concise summary of gerund [in p.66](https://books.google.com/books?id=oCBCDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA66&lpg=PA66&dq=%22The%20Gerund%20usually%20expresses%20an%20action%20of%20the%20main%20subject%22&source=bl&ots=kynB3w21wl&sig=ACfU3U2efMfKYn0MCPalNcUw6u8Y_AEJ5g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJnpjbnYX7AhUyuqQKHSP3DMYQ6AF6BAgJEAM#v=onepage&q=%22The%20Gerund%20usually%20expresses%20an%20action%20of%20the%20main%20subject%22&f=false)

> 136. **The Gerund** usually expresses an action of the main subject, as **vires acquirit eundo** Virg. *Aen.* iv. 175: but sometimes it is impersonal, as **nomen ipsum carendi** Cic. *Tusc.* i 36 87. Sometimes the object of the gerund is the same as the subject of the verb, so that the gerund appears to be passive: as **alitur vitium vivitque tegendo** Virg. *Geo.* iii 454: **lentescit habendo** ii 250: **cantando rumpitur anguis** *Ec.* 8 72: **ante domandum ingentes tollunt animos** *Geo.* iii 206. Or the gerund and verb have the same object and not same subject: **pueros excercendi causa producere** Liv. v 27 2

To summarize: We have examples of the gerund used passively, though they are few in number. Grammarians, for a reason I could not understand, prefer to call it "appears to be passive" where I never see them condemn the regular case as "appears to be active"

Answer (score 3):

I will quote from Himes' Grammer (1894) v2 p. 494:

> The Gerund used Passively: The Gerund is occasionally used passively,
> e.g. Antonius hostis judicatus Italia cesserat spes restituendi ("of
> being restored") nulla erat. Erudiendi gratia ("for the sake of being
> taught") Athenas missus erat.

However, your phrase *cupido amandi* I think would normally mean "desire of loving", not "desire of being loved". The gerundive is the future passive and agrees with its subject, like an adjective, *femina amanda* = a woman to be loved.

Comment: Thanks. Good find. FWIW, the other day, I tried to look in PHI for all the occurrences of *cupido + gerund*: and indeed, as far as I could tell, all of them had an active meaning.